# Strapi - Configure with environment variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, environment, strapi

Using `strapi 1.5.4`.

Is it possible to configure strapi with environment variables?
If not, how do you configure strapi without committing/exposing your database credentials and other secrets?

```
module.exports = {
  "orm": {
    "adapters": {
      "disk": "sails-disk",
      "mysql": "sails-mysql"
    },
    "defaultConnection": "default",
    "connections": {
      "default": {
        "adapter": "disk",
        "filePath": ".tmp/",
        "fileName": "default.db",
        "migrate": "alter"
      },
      "permanent": {
        "adapter": "mysql",
"user": process.env.DB_USER,
"password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        "migrate": "alter"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the only way is to use a hook.
In my `server.js` file (I would move the config into it's own file and clean this up)

```
const orm = {
  "adapters": {
    "disk": "sails-disk",
    "mysql": "sails-mysql"
  },
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "adapter": "disk",
      "filePath": ".tmp/",
      "fileName": "default.db",
      "migrate": "alter"
    },
    "permanent": {
      "adapter": "mysql",
      "user": process.env.DB_USER || 'root',
      "password": process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'password',
      "database": process.env.DB_NAME || 'test',
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "migrate": "alter"
    }
  }
};

(function () {
  const strapi = require('strapi');
  // Use a hook to override the config
  strapi.on('hook:_config:loaded', () => {
    strapi.config.orm = orm;
  });
  strapi.start();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to manage your secrets: https://github.com/cyberark/summon
The above plugin will provide more abstraction on your secret values, and they are supported bunch of [providers](https://cyberark.github.io/summon/#providers) too.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 Strapi offers a solution for this out of the box.

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#configuration-using-environment-variables